# Can't insert css file in html in spring

Tags: html, spring

Hello i'm trying to import css file in html view in Spring. But i don't know why its not working.I searched here but also couldn't fix it. Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang = "en" xmlns:th="http://thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,700" rel="stylesheet">
    <title>Login</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./login.css">
</head>
<body>
<div class="signup-form">
    <form method="post">
        <h2>Login</h2>
        <p class="hint-text">Log in to your account & have fun.</p>
        <br />
        <div style="font-weight: bold" class="text-danger" th:if="${error} != null" th:text="${error}"></div>
        <br />
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="username" placeholder="Username" required="required" />
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password" placeholder="Password" required="required" />
        </div>
        <div class="form-check">
            <label class="form-check-label">
                <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" />
                Remember Me
            </label>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-lg btn-block">Go In</button>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

[Here is an image of my files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wNvCb.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a CDN, but that won't help you unless you also get bootstrap's dependencies from a CDN or import them into your project. Below thing can help you. You can find these in the Getting Started of most versions of bootstraps documentation.

```
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3./css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```